# Different text orientation in the same HTML page

Tags: html, multilingual

I have an HTML page and I would like to display a paragraph in English and a paragraph in Arabic. The problem is the text-orientation. I set the parameter dir='rtl' on the HTML element but this makes so that the English text is somehow floated right, plus the last character I type will be displayed as first. For example, writing `<p style='border-right: 1px solid black'>Ciao</p>` I want to get:

```
Ciao!                |
```

But I get:

```
                !Ciao|
```

Any idea about how to achieve the desired result? 
Complete markup example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar" lang="ar" dir='rtl'>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
    نشجع كافة المعجبين على صفحة "سواروفسكي" على التوا
    </p>
    <p>Hello I am an English text!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use direction:rtl or ltr in CSS that will solve your problem

Comment: Wow, I did not know it would overwrite the page settings :) Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First I recommended the CSS property `direction: ltr;` to solve the problem. That is from a semantic markup point of view definitely not the way you wanna go, like @JukkaK.Korpela pointed out. Because I am not able to delete this accepted answer, I decided to edit it:

Set the `dir="ltr"` attribute ([W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-dir-attribute)) of the `p` element which contains English. A good practice is to set the language attributes `xml:lang="en"` and `lang="en"` as well.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar" lang="ar" dir='rtl'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
    نشجع كافة المعجبين على صفحة "سواروفسكي" على التوا
    </p>
    <p dir="ltr" xml:lang="en" lang="en">Hello I am an English text!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: “Authors are strongly encouraged to use the dir attribute to indicate text direction rather than using CSS, since that way their documents will continue to render correctly even in the absence of CSS (e.g. as interpreted by search engines).” http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-dir-attribute

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You are absolutely right the `dir` attribute is definitely the better way to go. So I upvoted your answer. =)

Answer (score 3):

You should set the [`dir` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-dir-attribute) to the value `ltr` or `rtl` according to the writing direction of the content of each element. Thus, if you have Arabic and English on the same page, you should set it e.g. as follows (assuming that the *main* language of the page is Arabic):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar" lang="ar" dir='rtl'>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
    نشجع كافة المعجبين على صفحة "سواروفسكي" على التوا
    </p>
    <p xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir='ltr'>Hello I am an English text!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The key difference is the `dir` attribute on the `p` element containing English. The language attributes are independent of this, but it is logical and good practice to set the language of each paragraph that is in a language different from the main language.

The `dir` attributes are not always necessary, since the inherent directionality of characters takes care of writing direction for the most of it. But when direction has been set to `rtl`, default alignment is to the right, and a simple way to override this is to set the direction to `ltr` when needed. Moreover, some punctuation and other characters may get into wrong positions if the direction is not set correctly, so it is good practice to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **dir='rtl'** in html tag.use it in **paragraph** tag

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar" lang="ar" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <p dir='rtl'>
    نشجع كافة المعجبين على صفحة "سواروفسكي" على التوا !
</p>
<p>Hello I am an English text !</p>
</body>
```

if you want to display both English and Arabic paragraphs right opposite to each other you have to use tables.